# How to pair a list of bluetooth enabled device programmatically in android?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I need to connect a list(more than one ) of bluetooth enabled android device programmatically.I got number of device with bluetooth enabled and sorted it in a list, While trying to pair it pairs with first device and the loop ends.

```
 if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                pairAllDevice(mDeviceList);
                showToast("finished");
                display();

            }
 private void pairAllDevice(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> data)
    {
        if(!pairedDevice.isEmpty()) {
            pairedDevice.clear();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
        {
            pairDevice(data.get(i));
        }
    }
```

This is the function to pair

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        pairedDevice.add(device);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error","connecting");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have implemented implicit paring so my application on the other-end get auto paired, But for now its works for only one devices from the list..

Answer (score 0):

The createBond method doesn't throw an exception, it simply returns false on immediate error. But, if it does return true, it still doesn't mean the bonding process was successful.  You should register for ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED, and see if you get any values from there (and only then add the device to the list).

Also, in your code you don't wait for the bonding process to finish on one device before creating a new bonding process. I'm not sure if this is something android can't handle, but if I were you, I would wait for one bonding process to finish before starting a new one